# web api different field combinations on one single model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Say I have the following model:

```
class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

For a list view in the client I would only need the following:

```
class ProductListView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

For a detail view I would need the following:

```
class ProductDetailView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

For an update of the name, I would need:

```
class ProductUpdateName
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

For an update of the description and brand, I would need:

```
class ProductUpdateDescriptionAndBrand
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

For all these different combinations, do I create the same number of classes? This sounds horrible though.

I can do anonymous classes instead but then I would need reflection to figure out the actual fields. This also sounds wrong.

So what is the best way?

Comment: I was exactly looking for something similar to this. What I am currently doing is, having a separate model class for each case. But, the `GraphQL` looks interesting in this case. Did you explored it?

Comment: @Thangadurai Thanks for bringing that up. I had a brief look at it. It looks interesting. What I am currently doing is make all fields optional, and only populate those fields needed for each case.

Comment: But the flaw is that the client knows the exact metadata of each class. But sometimes I don't want the client, say a normal user, to know about the existence of some admin only fields.

Answer (score 1):

A DTO by nature should represent a particular use case. The class is a representation of the data that will be transferred - hence the name. As such, whenever there's different data, yes, you should have a different DTO.

Now, that doesn't stop you from building upon your DTOs via inheritance. For example, `ProductDetailView` could inherit from `ProductListView`, since it is a superset of the properties of `ProductListView`. However, you should not inherit from `ProductUpdateDescriptionAndBrand`, because that includes an `Id` property, which `ProductDetailView` does not.

In those cases, you can opt to employ composition instead. For example, you could have something like:

```
public class BrandDescription
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
public class ProductUpdateDescriptionAndBrand
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public BrandDescription BrandDescription { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDetailView : ProductListView
{
    public BrandDescription BrandDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise, then just keep the classes as they are and use all of them as appropriate. Remember also that each of these serves a particular purpose (representing a particular group of data being transferred). As such, a property like `Description`, doesn't necessarily mean the same thing in all places. Just because the properties are similar or named the same doesn't mean they are handling the same concept(s).